# Is it better to use regex or some other search technique for large datasets?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, bigdata

I'm searching a very large text database file (5+ GB) line by line for a specific pattern and storing any positive hits in a hashmap.

The lines I'm looking for in the file contain what is known as a netblock ip range. Those lines look like this:

```
inetnum:(0.0.0.0 - 0.0.0.0)
```

The 0's can be any ip address. The first numbers will always be the smaller number because they represent the start address, and the second larger number is the end address for a specific range.

currently I'm searching for lines that match by using regex like this:

```
        //Regex pattern that will match an ip range in the form: 0.0.0.0 - 0.0.0.0 where any 0 can be replaced with an integer from 1 to 255
    String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =  "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
                             +  " - "
                             +  "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);

    boolean isMatch;
    String line;
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader("Foo.txt"); //foo.txt is a database text file.
    String[] ips;
    Scanner keys; // takes input from keyboard
    Map<String, String> sourceMap; // stores the start ip as the key for each netblock data structure.        

    // read each line and use the regex pattern to determine if the line has an ip range
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        isMatch = matcher.find(); // I tried doing this without using a boolean, but it didn't work for some reason... not sure why.
        if (isMatch) {
            ips = line.split(" - "); // split the start and end address into the ips array, remove the dash and space characters from the strings.
            sourceMap.put(ips[0], ips[1]); // insert the start ip address as the key and the end ip address as the associated string with that key.
        }
    }
    bReader.close();
    if (sourceMap.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Unable to read any usable data in file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

The problem with my code here is that it seems to run slower than my initial naive method, which is to check the length of each line, and check if the line contains the word "inetnum". That looked like this:

```
   if(line.length() >= 27 && line.length() <= 43 && line.contains("inetnum"){
       //foo
   }
```

The method below seems to run faster than using regex to match the pattern, but I'm worried about accuracy. Is one better than the other, or is there an alternative solution that I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: I'm going to argue and say this is totally dependent upon the data you have and the data you're searching for.  If your dataset is well formatted and you know what you're searching against you can seek out the optimal search methods.  If you don't know what your data is then you have to worry about accuracy and you won't be able to focus on optimal search approaches.  So, for what you've described I don't believe there will be an answer for you.

Comment: Java regex is pretty slow.  The first thing to try would be to use your simple test first, and then only use the regex on the lines that pass that.

Comment: Ot even strengthened to `line.startsWith("inetnum:(")`.

Comment: Why not do a coarse check first, based on line length and whether it contains `"inetnum"`, and within only those lines do your regex check?

Comment: I like the idea of doing a coarse check, I'll try that.

Comment: Your second cause is a much simpler check. If you need the speed, use it, however if you can afford the time, the pattern match is a stronger check. As pointed out, you can avoid using the regex unless it has a reasonable chance of being a match.